# Scraping Javascript Generated Content in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I find web scraping tasks in R can often be achieved with easy to use `rvest` package by fetching the html code that generates a webpage. This „usual“ approach (as I may call it), however, seems to miss some functionality when the website uses Javascript to display the relevant data. As a working example, I would like to scrape news headlines from [this](http://www.nestle.com/media/news-archive#agregator-search-results) website. The two main obstacles for the usual approach include the „load more“ button at the bottom and the extraction of the headlines using xpath. In particular:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url = "http://www.nestle.com/media/news-archive#agregator-search-results"
webs = read_html(url)

# Headline of the first news based on its xpath
webs %>% html_nodes(xpath="//*[@id='agregator-search-results']/span[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]/span[1]") %>% html_text
#[1] ""

# Same for the description of the first news
webs %>% html_nodes(xpath="//*[@id='agregator-search-results']/span[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]/span[2]") %>% html_text
#[1] ""
```

Maybe someone can shed light on (one of) the following questions:

1. Do I miss something obvious here? That is, is it possible to scrape the headlines using the usual approach based on `rvest` in this case? As to my current understanding, however, that is not the case.
2. Is `RSelenium` and `phantom JS` the only way to go here? To put it different, can the task be achieved without the use of `RSelenium` and `phantomJS`, in particular? This could include either the extraction of the headlines or loading more headlines (or both).

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Imo, it's sometimes better to look for the raw data in the background:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)
n <- 8 # number of news items to pull
useragent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
url <- sprintf("http://www.nestle.com/_handlers/advancedsearch.ashx?q=Nestle%%2Bdaterange%%3A..2016-01-05&index=0&num=%d&client=Nestle_Corp&site=Nestle_Corp_Media&requiredfields=MediaType:/media/pressreleases/allpressreleases|MediaType:/Media/NewsAndFeatures|MediaType:/Media/News&sort=date:D:R:d1&filter=p&access=p&entsp=a&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&ProxyReload=1&exclude_apps=1&entqr=3&getfields=*", n)
json <- getURL(url, useragent=useragent)
res <- fromJSON(json)
df <- res$GSP$RES$R
head(cbind(df[, c("U", "T")], df$FS$'@VALUE'))
#                                                                                                U                                                                                 T df$FS$"@VALUE"
# 1                                   http://www.nestle.com/media/newsandfeatures/nestle-150-years &#39;Good Food, Good Life&#39;: Celebrating 150 years of <b>Nestlé</b> <b>...</b>     2016-01-01
# 2                                   http://www.nestle.com/media/newsandfeatures/2015-in-pictures                                           2015 in pictures | <b>Nestlé</b> Global     2015-12-23
# 3                         http://www.nestle.com/media/news/nescafe-dolce-gusto-expands-in-brazil                Coffee superstar: Nescafé Dolce Gusto expands in Brazil <b>...</b>     2015-12-17
# 4                        http://www.nestle.com/media/news/nestle-waters-new-bottling-plant-italy  <b>Nestlé</b> Waters needs youth, for its new bottling plant in Italy <b>...</b>     2015-12-10
# 5 http://www.nestle.com/media/news/nestle-launch-wellness-club-personalised-health-service-japan     Matcha made in nutritional heaven: <b>Nestlé</b> launches Wellness <b>...</b>     2015-12-08
# 6        http://www.nestle.com/media/news/nestle-completes-chf-8-billion-share-buyback-programme          <b>Nestlé</b> completes CHF 8 billion share buyback programme <b>...</b>     2015-12-07
```

`df` contains more information, some of which prly has to be unnested if you want to use it.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this approach! I will have to look at it in some more detail. How did you actually get the extended url?

Comment: Can you pull more news items this way? In particular, if the number of available items is not known.

Comment: I don't know what's max for `n` .