# Reading table from webpage to R

Tags: r, excel, data-extraction

I am trying to read the webpage(http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/west-texas-intermediate-wti-crude-oil-calendar-swap-futures_quotes_settlements_futures.html. I am using the following code(which I found as another question on stackoverflow), but unfortunately I just get no values-just NULL. What's the problem? I also tried to open the link in excel directly(Power query)-but the table just doesn't show up? My ultimate aim is to have this data in excel and update it automatically everyday-but VBA doesn't work and the R script is also not working.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(rlist)
theurl <- getURL("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/west-texas-intermediate-wti-crude-oil-calendar-swap-futures_quotes_settlements_futures.html",.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
tables <- list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
tables[[which.max(n.rows)]]
```

Comment: Have you downloaded data from this site before? I have tried several things with R and Libreoffice but it seems to be returning an empty table for all attempts. It is possible the data is protected in some way so that you cannot download it.

Comment: it used to work before....I don't think the data is protected because if you open the webpage,you can copy the data without any problem.

Comment: the table is being generated dynamically in js, html source of rows and columns is empty; maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616350/scraping-javascript-generated-content-in-r

Answer (score 0):

ok, it works when using with `rselenium`:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(rlist)
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/west-texas-intermediate-wti-crude-oil-calendar-swap-futures_quotes_settlements_futures.html")
remDr$getTitle()
[[1]]
[1] "WTI Financial Futures Settlements - CME Group"
s = unlist(remDr$getPageSource())
tables <- readHTMLTable(s)
tables <- list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
tables[[which.max(n.rows)]]
```

result `head(tables[[which.max(n.rows)]])`:

```
Month Open High Low Last Change Settle Estimated Volume Prior Day Open Interest
1 MAY 18    -    -   -    -   -.41  70.24              249                  12,547
2 JUN 18    -    -   -    -   -.62  70.61              948                  11,406
3 JLY 18    -    -   -    -   -.58  70.34               26                   9,203
4 AUG 18    -    -   -    -   -.52  69.94               26                   8,642
5 SEP 18    -    -   -    -   -.45  69.53               26                   8,627
6 OCT 18    -    -   -    -   -.42  69.11               38                   8,360
```

how to simply set up `rselenium?` https://ropensci.github.io/RSelenium/articles/RSelenium-docker.html

when installing `rselenium` and dependencies use `devtools` as some packages are not present in CRAN:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
devtools::install_github("johndharrison/wdman")
devtools::install_github("johndharrison/binman")
```